# How can I periodically get new access_token using sasl with oauthbearer for kafka producer and consumer using kafkajs before the token expires?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, oauth, sasl, kafkajs

```
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');

var qs = require('qs');
var data = qs.stringify({
  'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  'grant_type': process.env.GRANT_TYPE 
});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN_PROVIDER_URL,
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data : data
};

async function getToken(){
  let token = await axios(config)
  .then((response) => {
      return response.data.access_token;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
  });
  return token;
}

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret:process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  brokers: [process.env.BROKER_URL],
  retry: {
    initialRetryTime: 100,
    retries: 2
  },
  // authenticationTimeout: 1000,
  // reauthenticationThreshold: 10000,
  ssl: true,
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'oauthbearer',
    oauthBearerProvider: async () => {
      const token = await getToken() //this is the function to get token
      return {
        value: token
      }
    }
  },
});

const topic = 'topic_test';
const producer = kafka.producer();

async function produceMesage(){
  try {
     await producer.send({
        topic: topic,
        messages: [
            { key: 'key1', value: message, partition: 0 }
        ],
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    //I want to avoid this error when token expires
    if(error.type =='TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED') producer.connect();
  } 
}

const run = async () => {
  await producer.connect()
  setInterval(produceMesage, 1000)
}

run().catch(e => console.error(`[example/producer] ${e.message}`, e))
```

this is my code to produce event and it works fine. I have a `getToken()` function to get the `access_token` to authenticate the producer/consumer connection. The problem is the `accesss_token` I am getting using `getToken()` function has a expire time of 32400 seconds or 9 hours and I want to keep producer running by getting new token before the token expires, what is the best way to that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help someone someday

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');

async function startProducer(kafka, accessToken) {
  try {
    // Create the producer
    const producer = kafka.producer();

    // Connect the producer to the Kafka cluster
    await producer.connect();

    // Set up the request options for the producer
    const request = {
      topic: 'my-topic',
      messages: [{ key: 'key', value: 'value' }],
      accessToken: { value: accessToken }  // pass the access token as a request header
    };

    // Send the message
    await producer.send(request);

    // Close the producer
    await producer.disconnect();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async function main() {
  // Set up the Kafka client
  const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'my-client',
    brokers: ['kafka1:9092', 'kafka2:9092']
  });

  // Get the initial access token
  let accessToken = await getAccessToken();

  // Start the producer with the initial access token
  await startProducer(kafka, accessToken);

  // Set up a timer to refresh the access token before it expires
  setInterval(async () => {
    // Check if the access token has expired
    if (Date.now() >= accessToken.expirationTime) {
      // Get a new access token
      accessToken = await getAccessToken(refreshToken);

      // Restart the producer with the new access token
      await startProducer(kafka, accessToken);
    }
  }, 60000);  // check every 60 seconds
}

main().catch(console.error);
```